# Is Witr obligatory after Taraweeh? How do you pray one raka Witr?

Tags: salat, taraweeh, witr

Do you have to end Taraweeh prayer by praying Witr? Is witr obligatory?

How do you pray only one raka (unit) of Witr? I tried to find out how to pray one raka but I didn't find any information online.

So you say the opening supplication and then recite surah al fatiha and then another surah. Then say allahu akbar while raising hand then place right hand over left hand on the chest then recite the Qunoot duaa? After that say allahu akbar and then go to rukku and finish the prayer normally?

Comment: These are three questions in one and I'd assume ar least two of them have answers on the site. See for example [What is the correct way of performing witr of 3 rakaats?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47524/what-is-the-correct-way-of-performing-witr-prayer-of-3-rakaats) and [Which one is Qunut?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/55426/13438)

Answer (score 1):

If you follow Fiqah Hanafi then in Hanafi fiqh Witr is 3 Rakahs and not one. You pray 2 rakahs and sit for tashahud then after reciting tashahud you stand up without saying salam then pray the third rakah, in this rakah after surah fatiha and other surah you say the takbeer and raise your hands to the ears (I'm sure you know the rest of the process).

One rakah is only permissible in such a situation when you are praying tahajjud in the night (2 rakahs after 2 rakahs after 2) and you fear that the time of fajr is approaching but haven't prayed Witr, only then you can stand up and pray one rakah of witr so that you will have prayed witr before fajr that is (without making it Qazah)

Comment: Please stick on answering the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have to end taraweeh by praying the 2 nafl so you pray your isha and then after the witr you pray your taraweeh and then end it with the 2 nafl